# SonarQube throws "Replace randomly generated values with fixed ones." for Test methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I use random `UUID` values in my test methods and get *"Replace randomly generated values with fixed ones."* error after pipeline. I am not sure if giving a fixed UUID value is a good idea. So, how should I create UUID variable properly in my test methods?

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    demoService.update(demoRequest, uuid);
}
```

Comment: Random values lead to the test changing every time. Say your test fails with “invalid id for demo HHH12335” or something along those lines. How are you going to diagnose and recreate? Depending on what you’re testing, a UUID of `00..-..-..00` or whatever will make your test _deterministc_.

Comment: So, what should I use? You explained everything except from the answer.

Comment: What about `UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("0000-00-00-00-000000")` ?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Chico? Any reply please?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would ask what do you need the UUID for? what are you testing?
is it a DB PK? are you starting from an empty DB?

if you use a random UUID, how do you retrieve the object to test it later?

Comment: I use Unit Test, for this reason it is not so important and I just want to know that how I should create uuid variable and value properly for Unit Test. I create long values e.g. ``123L`, then I think I should create uuid values in the same manner. Any idea?

Comment: What about `UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("0000-00-00-00-000000")` ?

Comment: Chico? Any reply please?

Comment: if your question is just "how do I create a uuid"? then your example is fine. a UUID is just a string.

Comment: I am confused. Because I am not sure if `UUID.fromString("0000-00-00-00-000000")` or `UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001")` is more correct? The first one is less digit

Comment: @Henry Using `UUID.fromString(`) will pad them with 0x even when you are short on digits.

You can still use     `final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();` just make it global on your Test Class, so all Tests reuse the same UUID instead of generating a new one :)

Comment: Thanks, but as ` UUID.randomUUID()` causing error on pipeline (SOnar does not like it), I am trying to create a static uuid by using the best approach. So, how would you define this variable?

Comment: @SMA Any reply please?

Comment: @AndyAspell-Clark Are you there? How to define a static UUID variable?

Comment: If you can paste the whole class that is causing you problems that would be great.

Comment: your suggestion to use `UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("0000-00-00-00-000000")` should work fine.